# Error detecting icon when publishing VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm putting together a VSCode extension and I've already packaged up the `.vsix` file a few times with no issue.

However, I've just added `"icon": "images/icon.png"` to the `package.json` and started getting an error message I just can't shake:

`Error: The specified icon 'extension/images/icon.png' wasn't found in the extension.`

The file definitely exists (though I don't quite understand why it looks for it under `extension` as a [hardcoded value](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-vsce/blob/master/src/package.ts#L593)).

I've tried setting the `baseImagesUrl` in the command line for packaging, but it seems to have made no difference.

Any help/insight here would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out the default `.vscodeignore` file that is dropped when you generate the extension boiler plate code has the `images/**` file ignored. That stops the `vsix package` command from pulling the icon into the package and it won't find it.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Perfect. The simplest answer is the most accurate. Good job.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but it came down to the fact that the package.json had trouble with a leading forward slash.  I am on windows, and was using "./" to prefix local resources in the README.md.   I thought this would also work in the package.json for the icon field, but it doesn't.  I removed the ./ and it started working find.  It doesn't recognize either "./" or "/" BTW.

Comment: Strange, I had the same issue on Windows but in the same package.json I'm using "./" to define a path to icons I'm using for a language file and that worked fine. It seems just an issue with the icon of the extension.

Answer (score 2):

I saved my icon with the name `"icon.PNG"` in the `"images"` folder and
in my `package.json` I used `"icon": "images/icon.png"`. It worked fine for me in the past but now I had to change it to `"icon": "images/icon.PNG"` (**case sensitive!**).

Comment: I also noticed the name of the folder matters too.  I had it has resources, changing it to images fixed it for me.  I don't know why it matters since the folder name is part of the setting.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem too.. I just renamed my icon from "Dark Icon 250.png" to "icon.png" and re-started vscode and vsce package worked.

Answer (score 0):

Move the logo.png from images/logo.png to the root and update the package.json with

```
"icon":"logo.png"
```

and vice package will work and the icon include in your extension